# Javascript- spawning creeps on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to spawn creeps on my canvas in a game I am making. The creeps should spawn on the canvas border in four random modes (start of x, start of y, end of x, end of y) and a random value for corresponding x or y from canvas.height or canvas.width. The code will explain it better I think:

```
//Creep Array- Creep() gets pushed into it later
        var creeps = []

//Random position generation    
        function Creep() {               
            this.XorY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
            console.log("Creep.XorY "+ this.XorY);
            if (this.XorY==0) {
                this.x=10
                this.y=Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height)
            }
            //.....
         }
//function Creep() continues with more if conditionals for spawn at X or Y axis
// I am getting error that the property height of undefined in anonymous function 
// Creep cannot be read. This is I think related to the canvas but the canvas var
// is declared at the top and defined later in the script as follows:

        window.onload = function() {
            // Nastavenie premennych
            button = document.getElementById("button")
            text = document.getElementById("text")
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
            requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
        }
```

Am I using the random function wrong or is there a problem with the flow of my code? I use the canvas to width and height property to draw my ship and that seems to work fine.

Comment: Try to use inspector and breakponts to find out why your properties are undefined at a specific moment. If the Creep function is called before the onload events fires then canvas and ctx are null (if defined before as you state)

Comment: you seem to generate the initial creeps before the onload. Hence canvas is not defined yet, that's why you get the error : perform all your inits in the onload handler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use the `height` of the `canvas` node in the `Creep()` function, but you're actually defining the `canvas` node later in the code.

So when JavaScript tries to read the `canvas.height` value, `canvas` isn't defined yet since it will get defined after the page finishes loading (window.onload).

Try putting `var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");` before defining the `Creep()` function.

Comment: Thanks I tried that as well, but it didint work so I simply put in the int value of the property instead of the property itself :/

Comment: Did you try to define the canvas element before defining the Creep() function? Also, don't define it inside a window.onload or any such event handler.